# I wrote same name of date column in my files but it's still errors

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest

I have looked this one up: KeyError: 'Date' How Can I fixed it?
I think I wrote date column's name that represent Date same as my files but it's still error

Here is my code:

```
!pip install yfinance
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf

# Load your historical data into a DataFrame (make sure to have a 'Date' and 'Close' column)
# You may need to preprocess your data to have the required columns
data = yf.download("^SET.BK", start="2012-01-01", end="2023-07-01")
date_column_name = 'Date'
close_column_name = 'Close'


data[date_column_name] = pd.to_datetime(data[date_column_name])
```

And this is error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

4 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Yfinance lib, is placing column 'Date' as index. If will look at the output directly from yfinance, you will see 'Date' column is lower then other columns headers. Adittionaly you can check, that with method data.info() it will show you 'Date' as index. Simple thing to make 'Date' as normal column is

`data.reset_index(inpalce=True)`

It should fix your problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. but Do you know Why I train the model and I get the predicted value of each day are the same?

Comment: You did'nt provide code for any type of model training, in adittion you're problem from question is around Key Error, so basically value of column name in DataFrame. If you have further problems with model itself, I would create another quesation related only to model training